# first activity not run, when i use serialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-activity, bundle

I am new in android. I want to send an object(object of p class) to first activity via onActivityForResult(). I write this code but when i use putSerializable(), first activity not run and i remain in MainActivity class. Why? How can i solve this problem?

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity implements Serializable{
PClass p;
...
Intent intent=new Intent();
if(resultCode){         
    if(json!=null){


        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("p", p);
        b.putString("result", json);
        intent.putExtras(b);

        }
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                }
                else
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                MainActivity.this.finish();    
  }
```

FristClass:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
Bundle b=data.getExtras();
    if(b!=null)
        p=(P)b.getSerializable("p");

        String result=b.getString("result");
     }
}
```

when i comment this line (b.putSerializable("p", p);) my FirstActivity run but if this line not comment, first activity not run and reamin on mainActivity class :(

Comment: your PClass class must implement parcelable. Also MainActivity does not extend Activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: MainActivity extends Activity and why i impelement Parcelable in PClass?

Comment: and PClass implements Serializable.

Comment: bcoz you want to pass object of pclass form one activity to another that's why and that's how its done in andorid

Comment: I am in MainActivity class and i want of this class send an PClass object to FirstClass. in MianActivity and PClass, i implement serializable but first activity not run. when i remove b.putSerializable(..) line of MainActivity class, FirstClass runs. WHy? what is problem of putSerializable(..)?

Comment: follow the link i posted and read the docs you will know why